# How to split the output and store it in an array?

Tags: bash

This is the output:

```
3,aac-lc, 93.8, aaclc, 77.3, h.264, 1024.6, h.264, 1029.1, 31, 31, 0,0,0.000000,31,31,0,0,0.000000,7,0,0,0.000000,30,1280 720,10,0,0,0.000000,30,1280 720
```

I tried with 2 scenario:

1. Storing in an array

   ```
     @arr=split(',',$stats);
     echo "statistics: $stats"
   ```
2. Storing in a variable

   ```
    echo $stats | cut -d ',' -f | read s1
    echo $s1
   ```

But neither scenario is working.

Comment: `awk '{ split("3,aac-lc, 93.8, aaclc, 77.3, h.264, 1024.6, h.264, 1029.1, 31, 31, 0,0,0.000000,31,31,0,0,0.000000,7,0,0,0.000000,30,1280 720,10,0,0,0.000000,30,1280 720
",arr,","); print arr[1]; }'`

OR

`echo "3,aac-lc, 93.8, aaclc, 77.3, h.264, 1024.6, h.264, 1029.1, 31, 31, 0,0,0.000000,31,31,0,0,0.000000,7,0,0,0.000000,30,1280 720,10,0,0,0.000000,30,1280 720" | awk '{ split($0,arr,","); print arr[1]; }'`

This should work.

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like this, for a single line of input:

```
IFS="," read -ra arr <<< "$foo"
```

Demo:

```
$ cat t.sh 
foo="3,aac-lc, 93.8, aaclc, 77.3, h.264, 1024.6, ..." # snipped

IFS="," read -ra arr <<< "$foo"
echo ${#arr[@]}
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[30]}
$ ./t.sh 
31
3
1280 720
```

Credits: [Split string based on delimiter in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash/918931#918931) answer by [Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb). Check the other answers there too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ set -f  # turn off globbing, so as not to expand wildcards
$ arr=($(echo "$stats" | sed 's/,/ /g'))
$ echo ${arr[1]}
aac-lc
```

Comment: Note that this will treat whitespace as separators as well as commas.

Answer (score 2):

Your first snippet is nothing like shell syntax. It is correct Perl syntax.
Your second snippet doesn't use `cut` correctly; I don't know what you intended.

The shell has a built-in string splitting construct: when you write `$somevar` without any quotes, the shell first looks up the value of the variable `somevar`, then splits that value into separate words on the characters specified by `IFS`, and finally interprets each word as a glob pattern (file wildcard). So you can split a string by setting `IFS` to the separator character and temporarily turning off globbing.

```
set -f; IFS=,
arr=($stats)
set +f; unset IFS
```

Note that if a field contains whitespace, the array element will retain that whitespace. If you want to split at all whitespace as well as commas, set `IFS=', '`. Note that `IFS` is not a string to split at but a set of characters to split at; either a space or a comma will constitute a separator. Furthermore, there are special rules for whitespace: any sequence of zero or more spaces followed by a comma followed by zero or more spaces will constitute one separator, and any sequence of one or more spaces will also constitute a separator.

If you only want to strip whitespace at the beginning or end of a field, you'll have to do it element by element.

```
shopt -s extglob
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
  arr[i]=${arr[i]#+( )}   # strip one or more spaces at the beginning
  arr[i]=${arr[i]%+( )}   # strip one or more spaces at the end
done
```