# How to split command's output and assigns result to an array using only a single expression?

Tags: zsh

**NB:** I've read the answers to other similar questions ([How to split the output and store it in an array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33038/10618), [How to split a string into an array in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129191/10618)), but none of them answer the specific question I'm asking here.

---

Suppose that the output of some command `foo` is a single line consisting of 10 tab-separated fields.  Then

```
tmpvar=$( foo )
fields=( ${(ps:\t:)tmpvar} )
echo $#fields
# 10
```

---

**Q:** How can I achieve the same splitting of `foo`'s output on tabs without needing an intermediate assignment to `tmpvar`?

---

FWIW, this does not work:

```
fields=( ${(ps:\t:)$( foo )} )
echo $#fields
# 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${(@ps:\t:)$(printf 'foo bar\t\tbaz')}"
<foo bar>
<>
<baz>
```

Or if you do want to suppress the empty elements like in your tempvar approach:

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' ${(ps:\t:)"$(printf 'foo bar\t\tbaz')"}
<foo bar>
<baz>
```

IOW, you need to quote the command substitution. Otherwise the `s:\t:` applies on the joining (with the first character of `$IFS`) of the fields resulting of the `$IFS`-splitting of the command substitution.

Alternatively, you could set `$IFS` to the empty string or to a single non-whitespace character.

```
$ (IFS=; printf '<%s>\n' ${(ps:\t:)$(printf 'foo bar\t\tbaz')})
<foo bar>
<baz>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should quote the $( foo )

```
fields=( ${(ps:\t:)"$( foo )"} )
echo $#fields
```

You can find [here some nice examples](https://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=" "; set -f
a=( $(echo -e "a b\tc d") )
printf '<%s>\n' "size=${#a[@]}" "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: `set -f` does something else in `zsh` (and command substitution doesn't undergo globbing there). In `zsh` like in `ksh93`, if you want word-splitting on TAB while preserving empty elements, you can use `IFS=$'\t\t'`. Using the `s` variable expansion flag is a lot better than changing a global setting IMO. Also note that the `-e` is implicit in `zsh`.